# PHP Regex: match character set OR end of string

Tags: php, regex

I am porting code from Node.js to PHP and keep getting errors with this regular expression:

`^/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)`

PHP complains about a dollar sign:

> Unknown modifier '$'

In JavaScript I was able to check if a string was ending with `[^0-9a-z]` or `END OF STRING`.
How do I do this in PHP with [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?
    $sExpression = '^/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)';
    if (preg_match('|' . $sExpression .  '|', $sUrl)) { 
        // ... 
    }
?>
```

The JavaScript code was similar to this:

```
var sExpression = '^/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)';
var oRegex      = new RegExp(sExpression);
if (oRegex.test(sUrl)) { 
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: `$` has a special meaning in regex. You have to escape that.

Comment: I am trying to match "END OF TEXT" with $

Comment: Then he will have to put it outside the group.

Comment: what php function are you using such as preg_match, preg_match_all, and well you do have this error "/[" literal "[" not character group. ^/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)

Comment: @Lex Podgorny: what is the whole piece of code? This regex looks fine.

Comment: What was the original JavaScript code?

Comment: @LexPodgorny Show us the original expression, yours don't give a very clear idea of whats your intention.

Comment: `/^[a-z0-9]{6}[^0-9a-z]?$/` should do the trick.

Comment: I am using `|` – please see my edit.

Comment: Well then don't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match a string that starts with a slash, followed by six alphanumerics and is then followed by either the end-of-string or something that's not alphanumeric:

```
preg_match('~^/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)~i', $str);
```

The original JavaScript probably used `new RegExp(<expression>)`, but [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) requires a proper enclosure of the expression; those are the `~` characters I've put in the above code. Btw, I've made the expression case insensitive by using the `i` modifier; feel free to remove it if not desired.

You were using `|` as the enclosure; as such, you should have escaped the pipe character *inside* the expression, but by doing so you would have changed the meaning. It's generally best to choose delimiters that do not have a special meaning in an expression; it also helps to choose delimiters that don't occur as such in the expression, e.g., my choice of `~` avoids having to escape any character.

Expressions in PCRE can be generalised as:

```
<start-delimiter> stuff <end-delimiter> modifiers
```

Typically, the starting delimiter is the same as the ending delimiter, except for cases such as `[expression]i` or `{expression}i` whereby the opening brace is matched with the closing brace :)

Comment: Jack, you are right, I should have shown the complete code – I am using "|" character as delimiter. So, I guess this is not the problem. Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: Yes it is the problem because your delimiter `|` is also part of your expression, this is why it thinks `$` is a flag, because it is right after a `|`.

Comment: @LexPodgorny Well, yeah, the expression itself is fine (I think).

Comment: You are absolutely right. Changing `|` to `~` fixed it. Thank you for taking time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

Fix the regular expression first:

```
^/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)
```

Try this.

As others pointed out, I'm an idiot and saw a `/` as a `\` ... LOL.

Ok, well go at this again,

I’d avoid using the "|" and just do it this way.

```
if (preg_match('/^\/[a-z0-9]{6}([^0-9a-z]|$)/', $sUrl)) { ... }
```

Comment: really, you think that is a valid regx?

Comment: I don't see how `^/` is valid either. Last I checked it was `/^`.

Comment: so a character group implied by {6} without an opening bracket is good syntax? shoot. lol @ me tired, I saw / as \ but still he needs to escape it surly

Comment: @zerkms - i'll blame that on dyslexia, but what is his delimiters is now the question.

Comment: He updated his question finally showing what was causing all this confusion. It turns out `/` wasn't meant to be the delimiter.

Comment: @zerkms i'm asked to the answerer. Look at his answer.

Comment: I realize my mistake, ok, lets move on, one shouldn't use the "|" as a delimiter I'm sure we can agree on that.

Comment: And also if we used `//` to denote a regex then we must escape `/` symbol.

Comment: @Avinash Raj - I had it backwards but check out this dandy '".*?(?<!\\\\)"|\'.*?(?<!\\\\)\'' http://regex101.com/r/lO4vY1/1

Answer (score 0):

Reducing this to just matching a particular character or end of string (PHP),

```
\D777(\D|$)\
```

This will match:

```
xxx777xxx or xxx777 but not xxx7777 or xxx7777xxx
```

Comment: `\D` will only match a single non-digital character.  Those `xxx` are misleading.